# NSMutableArray of UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nsmutablearray

In this small app, i simply want to make a questionnaire that displays each question on a UIView. Since the questionnaire may change in size depending on my needs, i would like to make the code very flexible by using for loops and an NSMutableArray to manipulate these UIViews. I have created the arrays and the views with the code below, however nothing shows up except for the purple UIScrollView. Can someone point out as to why the green UIViews are not showing up?

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *viewArray;
@property UIView *question1View;
@property UIView *question2View;
@property UIView *question3View;

@property UIScrollView *questionScrollView;
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize viewArray;

float viewHeight = 75.0;
float openViewHeight = 225.0;
float currentViewPossitionX = 0.0;
float currentViewPossitionY = 0.0;
float viewSpacing = 10.0;
int numberOfQuestions = 3;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setUpQuestionnaire];

}


- (void) setUpQuestionnaire{

    self.viewArray[numberOfQuestions] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [viewArray insertObject: _question1View atIndex:0];
    [viewArray insertObject: _question2View atIndex:1];
    [viewArray insertObject: _question3View atIndex:2];

    _question1View.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    _question2View.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    _question3View.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    float viewCount = 0;

    _questionScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds))];
    _questionScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    _questionScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds),(CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds)+100));
    [self.view addSubview:_questionScrollView];

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++){
        viewArray[i] = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(currentViewPossitionX, currentViewPossitionY, CGRectGetWidth(_questionScrollView.bounds), viewHeight)];

        [_questionScrollView addSubview:viewArray[i]];
        viewCount++;
        currentViewPossitionY += viewHeight + viewSpacing;
    }

    _questionScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds),(viewHeight * viewCount + 500));



}
```

Comment: Property 'backgroundcolor' not found an object of type`id`

Comment: Sorry, posted a slightly older version of what i have. I have edited the above code to match.

Comment: did you init your viewArray array? as I see in Your code self.viewArray[numberOfQuestions] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; is not init array code

Comment: every time your ` _questionScrollView.bounds
(origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 375, height = 667))` will be same

Comment: so you are using _question1View=[[UIView alloc]init];
    _question2View=[[UIView alloc]init];
    _question3View=[[UIView alloc]init];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your array init to the following,

```
self.viewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Initialise your views before you add them to your array,

```
_question1View = [[UIView alloc] init];
_question2View = [[UIView alloc] init];
_question3View = [[UIView alloc] init];
[viewArray insertObject: _question1View atIndex:0];
[viewArray insertObject: _question2View atIndex:1];
[viewArray insertObject: _question3View atIndex:2];
```

Finally just set the frame in your loop,

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) {
    UIView *view = viewArray[i];
    view.frame = CGRectMake(currentViewPossitionX, currentViewPossitionY, CGRectGetWidth(_questionScrollView.bounds), viewHeight);
....
```

After those changes it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++){
    UIView *aview=viewArray[i];
    aview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(currentViewPossitionX, currentViewPossitionY, CGRectGetWidth(_questionScrollView.bounds), viewHeight)];
    aview.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [_questionScrollView addSubview:aview];
    viewCount++;
    currentViewPossitionY += viewHeight + viewSpacing;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Custom UITableViewCell to achieve this. Advantages are
 - Easy customisation
 - No need to manage frame size as table view has own scroll view
 - Create model array for your all questions and just iterate it on UITableView

If you want to show same type of UI (Data will be changed as per item position) in list fashion go for tableview.